# How to prove a set is a core for an infinitesimal generator

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

I am trying to prove that the set $D=\bigcap_{n\geq 1} \{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) :f(0)=\sum_{k\geq 0} f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)\}$ is a core for the infinitesimal generator of reflecting brownian motion with jump boundary, i.e reflecting brownian motion which regenerates according to the density $g$ upon hitting $0$.

The generator of this process is given by $Af(x)=\frac{1}{2}f''(x)$ acting on the domain:
$Dom(A)=\{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) : f(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du\}$.

By assumption, we are given the fact that $\lim_{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du$.

Using the definition of a core, I basically need to show that the closure of the set $\{(f,Af):f\in D\}$ is equal to the set $\{(f,Af):f\in Dom(A)\}$, i.e for any $f\in Dom(A)$, I can construct a sequence of functions $f_n$ in $D$ such that $\lim_{n} f_n=f$ and $\lim_{n} Af_n=Af$.

However, I am not sure how to go about finding such a sequence of functions. My initial idea was to consider $f_n (x) = f(x)+\sum_{k\geq 0} f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du$. In this case, we would obviously have $\lim_{n} f_n=f$ and $\lim_{n} Af_n=Af$, but the problem is $f_n$ is not necessarily in $D$.
Any help or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: \cap is used in expressions like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$, and \bigcap is used in expressions like $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There is no way to help without  a definition of $g_n$.